# How can I reset pct change to NaN when another column value is different than previous row?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (df) like so:

```
Year |  Name  |  Count
2017   John       1
2018   John       2
2019   John       3
2017   Fred       1
2018   Fred       2
2019   Fred       3
```

`df['pct_chg']=df['Count'].pct_change()` yields

```
Year |  Name  |  Count  |  pct_chg
2017   John       1         NaN
2018   John       2         1
2019   John       3         .5
2017   Fred       1       -.66
2018   Fred       2         1
2019   Fred       3        .5
```

Keeping the columns the same, is there a way to get `pct_change()` to restart when `Name` is a new value? There does not seem to be any parameters to set this in the documentation.

desired output:

```
Year |  Name  |  Count  |  pct_chg
    2017   John       1       NaN
    2018   John       2         1
    2019   John       3        .5
    2017   Fred       1       NaN
    2018   Fred       2         1
    2019   Fred       3        .5
```

The change is superficial but it helps with eyeballing new names

Comment: df.groupby('Name').Count.pct_change()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can Use:

```
df['pct_chg']=df.groupby([df.Name.ne(df.Name.shift()).cumsum(),'Name'])['Count'].\
                                                   apply(lambda x: x.pct_change())
print(df)

   Year  Name  Count  pct_chg
0  2017  John      1      NaN
1  2018  John      2      1.0
2  2019  John      3      0.5
3  2017  Fred      1      NaN
4  2018  Fred      2      1.0
5  2019  Fred      3      0.5
```